# How can I implement nested [] operators in C#?

Tags: c#, oop

Consider a class of nested arrays, each element can be either an array or a number:

```
[[1, 2, [3, 4, [5]], [6, 7]], 8]
```

Here's my attempt to implement a [] operator for it.

```csh
class MyArray {

    List<MyArray> elements;
    int value;

    public object this[int index] {
        get {
            if (elements.Count > 0) {
                return elements;
            } else {
                return value;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So, the goal is to use it like the following:

```csh
MyArray arr = new MyArray();

... do something with the array here ...

int num = arr[3][5][1];
```

In case of accessing a "branch", not a "leaf" (say, arr[3][5][1] has multiple elements) let's just return 0, infinity or whatever integer is okay for us.

However, obviously, such nested operators won't work for my case, since the operator's result is an object, not a MyArray instance.

Right now, I see the only solution: define a conversion operator to int and make the [] operator always return just an element (which would be MyArray if we don't get an exception here). But is there any other way? Maybe, using something like an IList interface can help? Or maybe there's a way to define multiple possible return types for a method somehow? (but so far I googled it's not possible, and there's no an Either type in C#)

Comment: Side note: I would try to think of some other approach if you actually expect it to be used in code read/written by humans (not auto-generated code). I think `arr[3][5][1]` is not very readable code or code I'd ever want to write (maybe unless implementing  with matrix operations)...

Answer (score 4):

Your operator should return `MyArray`. In addition, you should implement an implicit conversion operator of `MyArray` to `int`:

```
class MyArray {

    List<MyArray> elements;
    int value;

    public MyArray this[int index] {
        get {
            return elements[index];
        }
    }
    public static implicit operator int(MyArray d) {
        return d.value;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the structure of `MyArray` is not homogenous: the compiler cannot know what it is going to get from the `[]` operator, yet you must specify the exact type.

One alternative would be to use `dynamic` in the return, but its use comes with significant performance penalties.

Comment: Hmm, maybe the `implicit operator` should go in the opposite direction? (Edit) Any `int` is a `MyArray` in a natural way, but not all `MyArray` represent just one integer.

Comment: @demeshchuk Yes, you are right, I just fixed it. Using `dynamic` may be another possibility (this is also in the last edit).

Answer (score 0):

What you are representing is a logical "tree" type of data structure, you simply want to use an indexer to access the elements (which is fine, if you tend to know the structure of the tree at compile time).

Usually with tree based data structures the composite pattern is applicable.  You have an interface that defines a node, and then two types of classes that implement it; one for leafs and one for parent nodes.  The node interface then has some number (or collection of) other nodes (which can be either implementation, or it can be an empty collection if it's a leaf node).

Here is a somewhat simpler implementation that doesn't use interfaces; it's not quite as robust (it relies more on conventions to tell you what's going on), but the concept is the same:

```
public class Node
{
    private List<Node> children = new List<Node>();

    /// <summary>
    /// This will have a non-null value if it's a leaf.  It will be null if it's not a leaf.
    /// </summary>
    public int? Value { get; set; } 

    public Node this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (children.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("This node has no children");
            }
            if (children.Count > index)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("This node doesn't have that many children");
            }

            return children[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, my goal was not to use a Value getter every time I want to get an actual value (this is supposed to be a JSON parser). Besides, I wouldn't use extra ArgumentException instances, since the default one (in case of an array overflow) is already declarative enough.

Comment: @demeshchuk I think the end result is preferable to use a value property.  It makes the code much clearer and easier to work with for others, even if it takes a bit more code to do it.  As for the argument exceptions, that's your choice of how to handle them.